Attach usb to cuttlefish device via crosvm
I have a problem when connecting usb to cuttlefish. I tried using crosvm to attach as follows:

$ sudo HOME=$PWD ./bin/crosvm usb attach 00:00:00:00 /dev/bus/usb/002/003 /tmp/cf_avd_1000/cvd-1/internal/crosvm_control.sock

However, this results in the following error:

error unexpected response: error: Input/output error (os error 5) [2024-06-05T05:05:50.295323432+00:00 ERROR crosvm] exiting with error 1: usb subcommand failed


I can't find the reason and have no experience with crossvm. In my opinion, crosvm was attached to cuttlefish so when starting cuttlefish, crossvm also starts, but with the default of no-usb.
